# Create table in db with mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

I have a question, I want to create a function for auto create table in my database.

I have my models 'MpModel.js' :

```js
//import connection
import db from "../config/database.js";

export const insertMpTab = (id, result) => {
    db.query(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mp_"+id+"` (`mpLine_date` date DEFAULT NULL, `mpLine_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`mpLine_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;", 
        [id],
        (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                result(err, null);
            } else {
                result(null, results);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

and controllers 'mp.js' :

```js
import {
    insertMpTab,
} from "../models/MpModel.js";

// Create new mp
export const createMpTab = (req, res) => {
    insertMpTab(req.params.id, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.json(results);
        }
    });
};
```

and routes.js :

```js
//import express
import express from "express";

import {
    createMpTab,
} from "../controllers/mp.js";

//init express router
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/mp/:id/", createMpTab)

//export default router
export default router;
```

I think my problem comes from my code. If you know or have an idea, even the docs that explains it because I haven't found it.

Thankyou

Comment: What problem are you experiencing? Can you add more details? Refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info on writing a good question

Answer (score 0):

Passing `[id]` to your query looks redundant, right now.

**Note:** If `id` comes from user input, it opens up the possibility for SQL injection. To overcome this, validate the variable, and reject any non-valid input.

```js
const tableName = `mp_${id}`;
const query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + tableName + "` (`mpLine_date` date DEFAULT NULL, `mpLine_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`mpLine_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci"
export const insertMpTab = (id, result) => {
    db.query(
        query, 
        (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                result(err, null);
            } else {
                result(null, results);
            }
        }
    );
};
```